# Discord.py commands run twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I only recently encountered an issue when using discord.py and the discord.ext commands extension to make a bot

When I call a command it runs twice, causing many bugs and errors. It only started happening after adding this command

```
@commands.command()
    async def afk(self, ctx, userMessage):

        #if user is already afk, remove them from the afk dict, if not add them to it
        if ctx.message.author in self.afkUsers:
            self.afkUsers.pop(ctx.message.author)
        else:
            self.afkUsers[ctx.message.author] = userMessage
```

however removing this command doesn't solve the issue. I was hosting on heroku but stopped that and ran it on my own pc to test but the problem still persisted . I used print functions in the commands to test if they were running twice and the strings inside them got outputted twice

I also have an on_message event

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        
        #if a member is mentioned but the member is afk, a message is sent
        textChannel = message.channel
        afkChannel = self.client.get_channel(690550327975346176)
        
        for member in message.mentions:
            if member in self.afkUsers:
                await textChannel.send(f"user is afk- {self.afkUsers[member]}")
            elif member in afkChannel.members:
                await textChannel.send("user is afk")
            

        #allows commands to work with on_message event
        await self.client.process_commands(message)
```

Edit: this also happens on some commands in my main file, but the strange thing is only some of them are affected

Comment: Do you have any `on_message` events?  If so, could you provide them?

Comment: yeah sure, I edited the post to include it

Comment: I tried your code with my bot and I didn't had any problems so your problem might come from somewhere else. Are you sure you stopped your heroku worker ?

Comment: yeah, in case I didn't could you tell me the exact way to do it? It shouldn't be that because  I added print statements that get printed twice to my terminal and if it was on heroku it would get sent to heroku logs instead

Comment: Also, it's not related to your problem but if you want your users to be able to write a sentence after !afk, you should replace `async def afk(self, ctx, userMessage):` to `async def afk(self, ctx, *, userMessage):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `process_commands` twice for the same message.  This is because the default `on_message` listener already calls `process_commands`.  So the `on_message` listener from your cog calls it a second time. You should remove the `process_commands` call from your cog `on_message`.

Comment: My bot relies on the on_message listener to format the message content and check who sent it before processing it. Is there a way to stop discord.py from processing commands by default instead?

Comment: Yes, if you register your own `on_message` listener in the bot itself, not in the cog, then it will replace the default one. You can just have it `pass` and not do anything